# Как в классе определить PDO

Tags: pdo, php, классы

Здравствуйте, пишу класс, в методах появилась необходимость использовать PDO.
Там где вызываю класс, там PHP видит PDO а в классе нет

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in
> /home/www-data/www/test/core/classes/Page.class.php
> on line 27
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function
> prepare() on a non-object in
> /home/www-data/www/test/core/classes/Page.class.php
> on line 27

Comment: Ну покажите же, что вы там понаписали то? Что за секретность?

Comment: Почитайте про Dependency Injection.

Comment: @zhenyab там просто выполняю запрос, ничего там интересного нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class DB{
    private static $_instance;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $password){
        self::$_instance = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    }

    public static function instance(){
        return self::$_instance;    
    }
}
```

В любом месте обратиться к инстансу можно через DB::instance();